# Xiaomi stuck in fastbot mode while bootloader is locked

Tags: fastboot, xiaomi, bootloader-lock, redmi-note-4

I've found my Xiaomi redmi note 4 stuck in fastboot mode after the battery had died. I tried different ways to unbrick it but nothing helps. The list of ways I tried:

1. platform tools fastboot binary. `fastboot reboot bootloader` - still
   rebooting to fastboot.[image]
   [image: says I can unlock it but...] Also, adb binary doesn't recognize my device.
2. I can't use mi unlock tool because it doesn't see my phone.
3. Miflash doesn't recognize the device also.

Are there any other ways to unbrick it?

Edit: It's Mediatek Helio X20

Comment: If your device is in bootloader/fastboot mode then adb does not work that is by design: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225159/2241

Comment: first i would try is, in fastboot mode keep holding Volume Up while `fastboot reboot` and release button when in recovery mode. there you can wipe cache

Comment: @alecxs still rebooting to fastboot. Do you know if there any mac os drivers from the examples above?

Comment: flash *boot recovery system* from SP Flash Tool. make sure you have the right scatter file. always flash with golden rules: ***"Download Only" + never flash preloader***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in fastboot mode. The reason was that my volume button was shortening and was always pressed. Fixing the button solved the issue.